# Setting a conditional background linear gradient for getTrProps in react-table not rendering correctly

Tags: css, reactjs, react-table

I'm trying to stylize a row in my react table so that when a certain row's data changes, the background has a linear-gradient applied to the row's background. I've tried a couple of things and looked up their documentation with examples with no luck.

I've tried a couple of things and looked up their documentation with examples with no luck.

I've made the linear gradient a variable and then plugged it into the conditional like so:

```
const gradient = {
  linearGradient: `(to left, #27293d 99%, #344675 1%)`
}
```

```
  const getTrProps = (rowInfo) => {
    if (rowInfo) {
      return {
        style: {
          height: `60px`,
          padding: `5px`,
          margin: `5px`,
          borderRadius: `5px`,
          backdropFilter: `blur(15px)`,
          background: rowInfo.status === 'created' ? linearGradient : `red`
        }
      }
    }
    return {};
  }
```

The column associated with the status in question is this:

```
    {
      Header: 'Status',
      accessor: 'status',
      Cell: row => (
        <div style={{
          width: `${row.value}%`
        }}>
          <span>
            { 
              row.value === 'created' ?  <GreenStatusCircle /> :
              row.value === 'awaiting_driver' ?  <YellowStatusCircle /> :
              row.value === 'delivered' ? <RedStatusCircle /> : "None Found"
            }
          </span>
        </div>
      )
    },
```

It should be rendering with the linear-gradient, but instead all of my rows are red. I've looked at the example shown here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/k3q43jpl47

And it seems I'm doing it just fine, but it won't render correctly.

Comment: `rowInfo.status === 'created'` is returning false.  It's hard to tell why that is from the code you've got here.

Comment: I'll edit it for clarity, that's my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass it as HTML attribute but not as style

Instead of:

```
const gradient = {
  linearGradient: `(to left, #27293d 99%, #344675 1%)`
}
```

Change it to

```
const gradient = {
  someColor: 'linear-gradient(to left, #27293d 99%, #344675 1%)'
}
```

and us it as

```
const getTrProps = (rowInfo) => {
    if (rowInfo) {
      return {
        style: {
          height: `60px`,
          padding: `5px`,
          margin: `5px`,
          borderRadius: `5px`,
          backdropFilter: `blur(15px)`,
          background: rowInfo.status === 'created' ? gradient.someColor: `red`
        }
      }
    }
    return {};
  }
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-gettrprops-h0oht